# Как вызвать контекстное меню с помощью элемента опционального меню?

Tags: android, menu, android-menu

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно вызвать контекстное меню выбрав элемент опционального меню?

В методе MainActivity определ переменную `MenuItem actionSetings` которой присвоил значение нужного элмента опционального меню в методе onCreate() `actionSetings = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);`
После в в методе, отвечающим за обработку выбора элемента определил действие при выборе `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

```
case R.id.action_settings:
                onContextItemSelected(actionSetings);
                break;
```

После чего в методе `onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)` отвечающим за создание контекстного меню определил создание меню при выборе нашего элемента

```
switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                menu.add(0, COLOUR_1_GRAY, 0, "set gray");
                menu.add(0, COLOUR_2_GREEN, 1, "set green");
                menu.add(0, COLOUR_3_YELLOW, 2, "set yellow");
                menu.add(0, COLOUR_4_BLUE, 3, "set blue");
        }
```

После чего в методе `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)` отвечающим за действие при выборе того или иного элемента контекстного меню определил некоторые действия.

Проблема в том что при эмуляции работы приложения при выборе того элемента в опциональном меню, который определил как глобальную переменную `actionSetings` возникает ошибка.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. Если есть возможность - то некоторые правила для вызова контекстного меню из опционального которые я не учел. В документации встречал PopupMenu, которое может спокойно заменить контекстное, но перед данным функционалом хотел бы понять причину ошибки.

Вот логи

```
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final, PID: 23971
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.view.MenuItem.getItemId()' on a null object reference
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final.MainActivity.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity.java:117)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:71)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2907)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:361)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:147)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:621)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:619)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19858)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
12-14 14:20:31.953 23971-23971/com.bestcompany.simplemenu4final E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

UPD Нашел ошибку в своем коде при выборе действия отвечающего за нажатие кнопки опционального меню. Строка onContextItemSelected(actionSetings); - не верная.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно вызывать контекстное меню по нажатию на элемент опционального. Метод `registerForContextMenu();` не позволяет использовать в качестве аргумента переменную actionSetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо:

1. В `onOptionsItemSelected()` при нажатии на нужный элемент вызвать контекстное меню методом `openContextMenu( View v )`
2. Всё. Вам не нужно хранить ссылки на элементы меню в активити.

Comment: Но у меня возникает проблема, такая же как и для Popup, так же как и registerForContextMenu(); - они принимают переменные типа View, но у меня данный элемент меню определен как MenuItem.

Comment: @mamba0767, вам надо контекстное меню прямо на строчке обычного меню?.. Если да, то это явно странный подход. Эти меню для этого не проэктировались. Вам надо либо `subMenu` в обычном меню делать или вызывать контекстное меню на любом другом View активити (т.е.передать в аргумент любой элемент разметки активити)

Comment: Возможно я некорректно поставил задачу для себя. Что имеем - OptionsMenu с некоторым количеством элементов, среди которых несколько в menu.xml имееют параметр app:showAsAction="ifRoom", тоесть отображаются левее трех кнопок, вызывающее меню. Я хочу вызывать либо Popup либо ContextMenu при нажатии на одну из кнопок, которая на самом деле является элементом меню, отображающихся всегда

Comment: @mamba0767, как меню отображается неважно. Важно то, что ContextMenu и Popup открываются с привязкой к элементу активити. Засим в методы их открытия надо передавать не элемент меню, а что-то из активити. Кнопку какую или `ImageView`, что-то такое. Но точно не `MenuItem`

Comment: Я правльно понимаю что [тут](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) картинка описывающая Popup меню - отображается не для OptionsMenu и параметром ifRoam, а для кнопок, которые очень похожи на элементы меню?

Comment: @mamba0767, если вы про меню, появляющееся под тремя точками справа вверху экрана, то это делается в обычном меню, в XML добавлением тега `menu` внутрь `item`. называется `subMenu` и легко гуглится)

Comment: Благодарю, действительно не верно понял спецификацию, спасибо